# Can I use Gaussian Optics and Aberration Theory to find the direction of a ray from the sensor to the world?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, camera

I am working on a master thesis which is a continuation of a previous one, which can be found here, with a nice summary: https://twitter.com/dearlensform/status/1465776613094797319

The thesis is mostly rooted in Computer Graphics, but I have been reading papers and textbooks for a while now and I still am in doubt if this can be done at all from a physics point of view.

The main idea of the original thesis (which is explained in section 4) is to condense a real lens (from a zmx file) to a handful of parameters, and then use those to reproduce the depth of field effect on an already rendered image with a depth map without actually tracing the optical system itself.

To do this, for each pixel of the image (in world space):

1. The entrance pupil is sampled, and the conjugate point on the exit pupil is then found using the pupil magnification;
2. The coordinates on the Gaussian Image Plane are found using the lateral magnification between world and image;
3. The aberration vector that describes the Third Order aberrations is computed and applied to the coordinates found in (2);
4. Using the Gaussian wavefront of the incoming light ray, we found a point on its circumference and use that point to trace a ray from the exit pupil to the sensor.

My "job" is to reverse this process and use the same technique to generate aberrated rays for a ray tracing rendering engine that will go into an unknown scene without actually ray tracing through the optical system (if not for the preprocess step).

So basically, for each discretized point of the virtual imaging sensor:

1. Sample the exit pupil and find the conjugate point;
2. Find the GIP coordinates;
3. Compute the aberration vector and apply it to the coordinates found in (2);
4. Use the wavefront of the light ray to find the direction of the ray before sending it into the scene;

I have spoken with an optic researcher and he told me that I cannot use the same approach of (4) to get the direction of the light ray leaving the lens, because aberrations affect a beam of rays and not a single one.

I still think that I should be able to sample one of the rays in the beam, but my knowledge here is still a bit spotty, I would appreciate some pointers in the right direction.

I am also not sure I can use the same approach used in the thesis to compute the aberration vector.

So the question, after months of failed attempts and researches, is the following:

**Does this makes sense physically? I know that light paths are valid both ways, but does this hold true even in this situation?
If it is physically sound and it can be done, would you be able to point me in the right direction?**

EDIT:

My current approach (not working) is the following:

1. Sampling of the exit pupil $P'_1$;
2. I compute Image Magnification and pupil magnification;
3. I get the entrance pupil conjugated point $P'_0$;
4. Get the Gaussian Image Plane coordinates;
5. Compute the distance between sensor and exit pupil (in the og thesis it was the distance between object plane and entrance pupil);
6. Compute the distance between entrance pupil and GIP z-coordinate (it was exit_pupil and GIP in the og thesis);
7. Get the z-coordinate of the GIP by subtracting the entrance pupil and the distance from (6);
   8)Find the Gaussian Ref. Sphere and get the point through which the ray will pass.

I believe that the steps to compute the distances, inverted from the original thesis, are not correct or do not work in this reversed approach and therefore the gaussian reference sphere is also wrong.

Comment: I do not see why not, you can change scene with sensor and its the same procedure. BUT: The biggest problem is that from scene to sensor you start with an "undistorted" image and see how your optical train distorts it onto your sensor, recreating an optical train sampling the world. The reverse is weird. Because you need to assume a perfect "sensor" (or display) and then just go through the same process and send out something simply affected by the optical train aberrations. However, as you are calling it still a sensor, I assume that what it was sampling was already distorted (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) but this distorted image that is your source is impossible to know without first going from scene to sensor. Its like trying to know how a song will be in the next 30s, after hearing only 20s of it (kinda). So, either you simply assume your sensor is instead a display, with a perfect image, then apply exactly the same algorithm to send an aberrated signal onto the scene, or if you require knowing an already aberrated signal as your source then its more complicated. You could try to find a representative transfer function and statically apply it to your input image, but im not sure

Comment: I don't think I understood the difference between the sensor and the "display". I did just reversed the whole process, using the distance between the the first element of the optical system from the sensor as the original "world distance" and the focus distance as an approximated real world distance. And I inverted the distances (like world-entrance pupil with sensor-exit pupil). I will update the question with more details

Comment: "A single lens" has horrible distortions and is basically useless in photography. That's why we design and build complex compound lenses that can have a dozen individual components or more and are close to ideal. The blur due to depth of field is NOT an effect of a non-ideal lens. It's an effect of the large aperture of an ideal one. So if you are trying to simulate nice "bokeh", then you have to use ray bundles rather than individual rays, which will always give you infinite depth of field. The guy who told you that was right IMHO.

Comment: @FlatterMann I'm sorry for the confusion, I've replaced "lens" with "optical system". For each frame during the simulation a ray leaving the sensor will pass through a different point in the exit pupil and therefore would be distorted differently and hit a different part of the scene, causing the circle of confusion that renders as depth of field. I don't fully understand why the approach proposed in the original thesis (scene->Sensor) works, but the reverse wouldn't

Comment: You are still exactly where you were in the beginning. The mathematics of lens aberrations was invented to design high quality optical systems, not to remove field of view blur. "Bokeh" is NOT a lens error. It's actually a design feature. All you need for it is the propagation of the light through an ideal lens of large diameter. Of course you can "simulate" that with gaussian blur, but that's just a crutch and it doesn't require any knowledge of the optical system in detail except for its aperture.

Comment: Oh I know that, I am not trying to replicate bokeh and dof as a lens error, those comes naturally by sampling the aperture. I want to replicate the aberrations trough gaussian optics + aberration vector as those affect the shape of the circle of confusion